# Python not reading pictures of a folder

Tags: python, image

I'm trying to loop and read the pictures of a folder and add it to my model. Some images re present in 2 folders, but for some reason it doesn't read from the file path.

```
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np
import joblib
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications import vgg16

# Path to folders with training data
dog_path = Path("training_data") / "dogs"
not_dog_path = Path("training_data") / "not_dogs"

images = []
labels = []

# Load all the not-dog images
for img in not_dog_path.glob("*.png"):
    # Load the image from disk
    img = image.load_img(img)

    # Convert the image to a numpy array
    image_array = image.img_to_array(img)

    # Add the image to the list of images
    images.append(image_array)

    # For each 'not dog' image, the expected value should be 0
    labels.append(0)
```

But im getting the below error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-0338d9d50366> in <module>
     15 for img in not_dog_path.glob("*.png"):
     16     # Load the image from disk
---> 17     img = image.load_img(img)
     18 
     19     # Convert the image to a numpy array

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\utils.py in load_img(path, grayscale, color_mode, target_size, interpolation)
    108         raise ImportError('Could not import PIL.Image. '
    109                           'The use of `load_img` requires PIL.')
--> 110     img = pil_image.open(path)
    111     if color_mode == 'grayscale':
    112         if img.mode != 'L':

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   2816     for message in accept_warnings:
   2817         warnings.warn(message)
-> 2818     raise IOError("cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp))
   2819 
   2820 

OSError: cannot identify image file 'C:\\Users\\Yeshan\\Desktop\\Ex_Files_Deep_Learning_Image_Recog_Upd\\Exercise Files\\Ch05\\training_data\\not_dogs\\._00381.png'
```

Comment: Are you certain, this is the file name: `._00381.png`? In case you are on Linux env, hidden file attribute may cause problems!

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```py
from PIL import Image
# ....

image = Image.open(img)  # don't use same variable names
```

Instead of:

```py
from keras.preprocessing import image
# ...
img = image.load_img(img)

# Convert the image to a numpy array
image_array = image.img_to_array(img)
# ...
```

Also, PIL supports numpy ndarray by default!